# Error importing libraries on Arduino IDE

Tags: c++, json, namespaces, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm using [Arduino UNO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino#ArduinoUno) and I need to parse a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) file wich might be quite big considering the microcontroller has only 2k of SRAM. I found this library ([stream_json_reader](https://www.biicode.com/lasote/lasote/stream_json_reader/master)) which can process the file char by char and seems suitable for my porpuses. The problem is I can't figure how to import it correctly in the [Arduino IDE](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software). So far I have my `Documents/Arduino/libraries` folder with `stream_json_reader` and `stringutils` (available [here](https://www.biicode.com/lasote/lasote/stringutils/master)). I have modified the `stream_json_reader.h` file to point to `cstringutils.h` (`#include "C:/Users/MY_NAME/Documents/Arduino/libraries/stringutils/cstringutils.h"`).

My code looks something like:

```
#include "stream_json_reader.h"
#include "stringutils.h"

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

using namespace lasote;

static const char* queries[] = { "response.current_observation.city", "response.current_observation.temp_c"};
StreamJsonReader jsonreader(queries, 2);

[...]

void setup() {
    // Retrieving JSON file
    [...]
}

void loop()
{
    [...]
    jsonreader.process_char(c);
    [...]
    Serial.println(jsonreader.results[0]);
    Serial.println(jsonreader.results[1]);
}
```

But I get: `...stringutils/stringutils.h:18: error: expected initializer before '<' token`

I have nearly zero experience with Arduino and C++. I don't if the problem is with some `#include` or if I misplaced the library files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error seems to be on the 18th line of the stringutils.h header file.  Can you post that file?

Comment: It's available [here](https://www.biicode.com/lasote/lasote/stringutils/master/5/stringutils.h).

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I work at biicode.

That is a library ready to use with biicode as explained on [this blogpost](http://blog.biicode.com/arduino-parse-json/). Biicode is a C and C++ dependency manager, it has a central online repository and is compatible con VCS.

To use that library, instead of: `#include "stream_json_reader.h"`

use: `#include "lasote/stream_json_reader/stream_json_reader.h"`

then execute `bii find` and `bii arduino:build` or `bii arduino:upload``to

Here's a getting started guide on biicode and Arduino:

http://docs.biicode.com/arduino/gettingstarted.html

Json-related libraries available in biicode: http://www.biicode.com/search?q=json